# Active directory and linux nslcd binding without extending the AD schema

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, openldap

I have a requirement of binding linux clients to Windows Server 2012 Active Directory. I have a test environment where I successfully did that both with samba-winbind-kerberos, and with nslcd, using a user to authenticate. However, when using samba-winbind-kerberos, I was able to achieve this without extending the AD schema to include UNIX attributes (UID/GID, Home directory, shell), because smb.conf have an option to idmap, specifying a starting range

```
idmap config *:range = 11000-20000
```

and this will take care of unix mapping of UID/GID of AD users.

If I do not enable UNIX attributes in AD, I will get an error in nslcd debug log, that says

```
uidNumber: missing
```

Is there any way to use the same feature in nslcd/libnss_ldap, so that I do not have to extend the AD schema on the Windows server 2012? I do not prefer to use samba on a production environment because of its remote code execution vulnerability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible right now. There is no id mapping available for nslcd according to their documentation, and this requires your AD schema to be extended to have unix attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Using CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) with nslcd version 0.8.13 against Windows 2016 AD without any schema extension, I was able to configure this and get it working properly today.

I've followed mainly the Serverfault article "[LDAP authentication on CentOS 7](https://serverfault.com/questions/633802/)" and had to use in `/etc/nslcd.conf` the section `Alternative mappings for Active Directory` and to `replace the SIDs in the objectSid mappings with the value for your domain`.

To "[Get SID by its objectSid using ldapsearch](https://serverfault.com/questions/851864/)" I've used the [linked script](https://serverfault.com/a/852338/448950/).

Other mapping were set to

```
filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(!(objectClass=computer)))
map    passwd uid           sAMAccountName
map    passwd uidNumber     objectSid:<yourValue>
map    passwd gidNumber     primaryGroupID
map    passwd homeDirectory "/home/$sAMAccountName"
map    passwd gecos         displayName
map    passwd loginShell    "/bin/bash"
map     group gidNumber      primaryGroupID
```

Comment: Thank you @U880D. I am not sure about Windows 2016, but with the version Windows Server 2012, the default schema doesn't come with the primaryGroupID which is mentioned in the  `map     group gidNumber      primaryGroupID`.

Comment: According MS documentation [Primary-Group-ID attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679375(v=vs.85).aspx) it should be there. However, you could also try to `map passwd gidNumber objectSid:<yourValue>
map group gidNumber objectSid:<yourValue>`, since this works in my setup too.

Comment: Indeed, the objectSid approach works on Debian 9 Stretch as follows:

`map    passwd uid           sAMAccountName
map    passwd uidNumber     objectSid:S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx
map    passwd gidNumber     primaryGroupID
map    passwd gecos         displayName

map    group gidNumber      objectSid:S-x-x-xx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx
map    group cn             sAMAccountName`